# What is the probability that a signal will include $3$ green, $2$ blue, and $1$ red flag if each of the six flags may be red, blue, or green?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

> A nautical signal consists of $6$ vertical flags. Each flag can be red, blue or green. Answer the following:
>   a) How many possible signals can be formed (e.g. 1st flag green, 2nd green, 3rd red, 4th green, 5th blue, 6th blue, is one possible signal)?
>   b) What is the probability that a signal formed will find the 6 flags in this configuration (but not only in this order): $3$ green flags, $2$ blue and $1$ red?

I am trying to do the above question. For part A, I am doing $6^3 = 216$ and for part B I am doing $\frac{(3!2!)}{216}$ to get $12/216$. Would that be correct in this question?

Answer (score 0):

Part a should be $3^6$. Because each flag can be one of three colours. The second one should be $\frac{\frac{6!}{3!\cdot2!}}{3^6}$.

EDIT: Explanation for answer to part b - There are 6 flags and the numerator counts the number of unique permutations when there are repetitions as in the question.

Comment: You should explain how you obtained the probability in the second question.

Answer (score 0):

> A nautical signal consists of $6$ vertical flags.  Each flag can be red, blue, or green.  How many possible signals can be formed?

Each of the six positions can be filled with one of three colors, so there are $3^6$ possible signals.

> What is the probability that a signal will include $3$ green, $2$ blue, and $1$ red flag?

Three of the six positions can be filled with green flags in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways.  Two of the remaining three positions can be filled with blue flags in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways.  The final position must be filled with a red flag.  Therefore, the desired probability is 
$$\frac{\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}}{3^6}$$